# Get clicked image id on dynamic div

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In here I am able to display university images on dynamically created div. Now I want to get id of the university image which user selected, then use that id to display courses which selected university offer. Is there way to do that?

```
  protected void fetchUniversities() 
  {
        List<University> uniList = new List<University>();

        using (var dd = new UniversityContext())
        {
            uniList = UniversityController.fetchUniversitiesOfferCourses(dd);
        }

        Literal header = new Literal();
        header.Text = "<div class=\"container\"><div class=\"row\"><h2>Apply For University</h2><p>Select your preferred university</p></div></div>";

        CompanyPanel.Controls.Add(header);

        foreach (var item in uniList)
        {
                Literal label1 = new Literal();
                label1.Text = "<div class=\"container\"><div class=\"row\" >";

                Literal lblTwo = new Literal();
                lable2.Text = "<img src=\"/template/images/" + item.ImageName + "\" height=\"100%\"/>";

                Literal lblLast = new Literal();
                label3.Text = "</div></div>";

                Panel1.Controls.Add(label1);
                Panel1.Controls.Add(label2);
                Panel1.Controls.Add(label3);   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of creating html dynamically you should use datalist, repeater or gridview control to show images. Use link button to show images in them and utilize itemcommand event to determine which image is clicked.

Comment: Check my answer here. It contains many elements you are looking for, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545970/how-to-pass-a-c-sharp-variable-as-a-commandargument-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this in a better way by moving to a different framework and return data (e.g. JSON) in response to an ajax query (have a look at ASP.NET MVC).

Here is a way to achieve this using your example, it's a bit cumbersome and I haven't tested it but should get you in the right direction

Add a method as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetUniversityCourses(int universityId)
{
    List<UniversityCourses> courses = ...
    StringBuilder coursesHtml = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var course in courses) {
        //Generate your html here
        coursesHtml.Append("<div>" + course.Name + "</div>";
    }
    return coursesHtml.toString();
}
```

Then add this javascript code to you aspx file:

```
function GetUniversityCourses(id) {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/GetUniversityCourses",
    data: {"id": id,
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
    },
    complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
        $("#coursesContainer_" + id).html(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

}

Then in your server side code:

```
lable2.Text = "<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-getcourseid=\"" + item.Id + "\"><img src=\"/template/images/" + item.ImageName + "\" height=\"100%\"/></a><div id=\"coursesContainer_\"" + item.Id + "</div><script>$('a[data-getcourseid=\"" + item.Id + "\"]').on('click', function() { GetUniversityCourses(" + item.Id + ")}</script>";
```

Comment: university courses will be displayed from sql databse, for that i need selected University id, then i need to display that course info in same web page, so using link will not the method I seek.Thank you! @Isma C.